# PHP and unit testing assertions with decimals

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, assert, precision

I have a method that returns a float like 1.234567890.I want to test that it really does so. However, it seems that this returned float has different precision on different platforms so how do I assert that the returned value is 1.23456789? If I just do:

```
$this->assertEqual(1.23456789, $float);
```

Then that might fail on some platforms where there is not enough precision.

Answer (score 89):

So far it hasn't been mentioned that assertEquals supports comparing floats by [offering a delta to specifiy precision](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.assertions.html#appendixes.assertions.assertEquals.example2):

```
$this->assertEquals(1.23456789, $float, '', 0.0001);
```

Thanks to @Antoine87 for [pointing out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55730734/642750): since phpunit 7.5 you should use `assertEqualsWithDelta()`:

```php
$this->assertEqualsWithDelta(1.23456789, $float, 0.0001);
```

Comment: Love the simple solutions. This should be the accepted one. Accepted solution would have me digging through BCMath for an hour.

Answer (score 12):

As an update to @bernhard-wagner answer, you should now use `assertEqualsWithDelta()` [since phpunit 7.5](https://github.com/ory/oathkeeper-client-php/blob/master/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/ChangeLog-7.5.md#added).

```php
$this->assertEqualsWithDelta(1.23456789, $float, 0.0001);
```

Answer (score 4):

In general, it's a bad idea to test built-in floats for equality. Because of [accuracy problems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems) of floating point representation, the results of two different calculations may be perfectly equal mathematically, but different when you compare them at your PHP runtime.

Solution 1: compare how far apart they are. Say, if the absolute difference is less than 0.000001, you treat the values as equal.

Solution 2: use [arbitrary precision mathematics](http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php), which supports numbers of any size and precision, represented as strings.

Comment: +1 for never testing floats for equality. Scary how many people are not aware of this. Wish I could upvote more...

Comment: Right, sleske. I learned it for real long time ago writing my own ray tracing program, and wondering why I only get several dots on the screen instead of beautifully lit polygons. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively of using bcmath() you can also set the default precision, like this:

```
ini_set('precision', 14);
```