# Laravel 10 test asserts float not equal to integer of same value

Tags: laravel, testing, casting

In my test I have the line

```
$this->post('/api/items', $item, [
    'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$plainTextToken
])
...
->assertJson(fn(AssertableJson $json) => $json
...
    ->where('price', Product::query()->find($item['product_id'])->price)
```

which produces the failure:

```
Failed asserting that 699 is identical to 699.0
```

even though both properties and db fields are set up exactly the same. The test passes if there is a decimal value (eg. 699.9)

I put the following in both models to try and match the types:

```
    protected $casts = [
        'price' => 'float'
    ];
```

Comment: have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1963077/php-and-unit-testing-assertions-with-decimals